# How can I store data to javascript global variable in jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have a jquery datatable which has large number of data. I am performing an action that selected(checkbox checked) rows will only be binded inside it. Now I have to reset the jquery datatable i.e all the records should be displayed again. So what should be the approach? whether I need to store data into **global variable** and then clear it and assign this data again to Datatable or some another approach.

```
////////// on document.ready/////////
$('#mytable').DataTable();
 GlobalTable = $('#mytable').DataTable();
 GlobalTab = GlobalTable.data();


/////////the below code is for Binding the data again/////////
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
table.clear().draw();
for (i = 0; i < GlobalTab.toArray().length; i++) {
     table.row.add(GlobalTab.toArray()[i]).draw();
   }                  
 table.draw();
```

These above lines I have tried which is not working properly as expected.

Comment: What is not working; Can you share a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for this it would be easy to debug;

Comment: _"not working properly as expected"_.. Can you share a demo of the same ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I can share above mentioned code only.
I do have a table id=mytable
I have made data to be looped in TR. Now I have a Dropdown with two options. One is View All and View Selected. After selecting VIEW SELECTED the data is binded successfuly. But When I select **View All** it shows the same filtered data. Here I have to Bind the Datatable again. And here is the remaining code above.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what was not working about your code (couldn't reproduce with your snippets), but I can suggest a couple of things:

- Store only the data in the variables: `GlobalTab = GlobalTable.data().toArray()`
- You do not need to redraw after clearing the table, or after adding each row, you only need to redraw when you are finished changing the data
- You don't need to iterate over the rows, you can add them all in a single call

So to bind the data again you would do something like:

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
table.clear();
table.rows.add(GlobalTable);
table.draw();
```

You can see a working example in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/angelalb/pf1oqjn3/1/)

Comment: from this `GlobalTab = GlobalTable.data().toArray()` I am getting collection of array like this-**Array[129]
[0 … 99]
[100 … 128]** but in JSFiddle it shows Single Output only.

Comment: Also when I tried this- `table.rows.add(GlobalTab)` The GlobalTab contains Array[129]. But it adds only some records which I have selected for filters.

Comment: @Puneet_2696717 I think this `Array[0...99][100...128]` is just how the console shows large arrays, just to simplify browsing through them. Also, if your datatables has filters, it will only show the data that passes the filters. All the items are in the datatables, it's just not showing some of them.

Comment: Actually I am binding a datatable with 129 rows with pagination. and select checkbox is also provided. We do have a dropdown to select- View All and View Selected. When I select **[View selected]** only selected rows are binded. But when I select **[View All]** it is not binding All the Records thats why I have asked for this solution.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you without reproducing the issue. Maybe you could try to reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: It is Resolved. I have used ext.search which is written on dropdown change. I have moved the Code out of the scope and it works perfectly fine.